# Iteration of dividing columns, matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From the following dataframe:

[image]

I want to divide each column just by the column before that one: what i mean is

```
column[2] / column[1]
column[3] / column[2]  
column[4] / column[3]  
column[5] / column[6]  
column[7] / column[8]
...
column[13] / column[12]
```

Comment: Ok, so presumably you coded up your presumed approach and will share it with us. What was wrong with it? Errors?

Comment: I dont even know where to start :(

Comment: With Google. You have a decent enough idea of the problem description. Please don't just throw it to SO in place of doing even basic research.

Comment: maybe search `pct_change + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pct_change is giving you the relative change from row to row or here column to column (see also the comment of @W-B).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])  # toy dataframe

print(df)

df_new = df.pct_change(axis=1) + 1

print(df_new)


xxx@yyy:~/Desktop/test$ python test.py                                                  
   0   1   2   3                                                                                      
0  1   2   3   4                                                                                      
1  5   6   7   8                                                                                      
2  9  10  11  12                                                                                      
    0         1         2         3                                                                   
0 NaN  2.000000  1.500000  1.333333                                                                   
1 NaN  1.200000  1.166667  1.142857                                                                   
2 NaN  1.111111  1.100000  1.090909
```